# OpenCV Disparity map post-filtering using only one depth image

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, image-processing

OpenCV has a tutorial on post-filtering disparity maps [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html) but it needs the left and right images to function properly. 
Is there a way to do this using only one depth image which we have acquired beforehand?

From this:

[image]

To This:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d51/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1DisparityWLSFilter.html#details):

> Disparity map filter based on Weighted Least Squares filter (in form of Fast Global Smoother that is a lot faster than traditional Weighted Least Squares filter implementations) and optional use of left-right-consistency-based confidence to refine the results in half-occlusions and uniform areas.

I think you can use the [filter](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d72/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1DisparityFilter.html#a3dc752f1760b375f1ea12173c1f07a9e) method after converting your depth map to a disparity map.

However, I would recommend a bilateral filter to filter/clean the depth map as it is generally used in the literature for depth maps.
Here is the OpenCV documentation page associated to the [bilateral()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed) function. There is also a CUDA version.

For example, the [OpenCV odometry_evaluation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/246ea8f3bdf174a2aad6216c2601e3a93bf75c29/modules/rgbd/samples/odometry_evaluation.cpp#L226) uses a bilateral filter.